# Using adply in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, plyr

I have a big data.table that looks like:

```
dt<-data.table(start=c("2012-07-13 23:45:00", "2012-07-14 15:30:00", 
                       "2012-07-14 23:57:00"), 
               end=c("2012-07-14 00:02:00", "2012-07-14 15:35:00", 
                     "2012-07-15 00:05:00"), id=c(1,2,1),cat=c("a","b","a"))
dt
                 start                 end id cat
1: 2012-07-13 23:45:00 2012-07-14 00:02:00  1   a
2: 2012-07-14 15:30:00 2012-07-14 15:35:00  2   b
3: 2012-07-14 23:57:00 2012-07-15 00:05:00  1   a
```

I need to get an output that shows total minutes of event on each calendar day by id and category. Using the example above the output should be:

```
          day id cat V1
1: 13.07.2012  1   a 15
2: 14.07.2012  1   a  5
3: 14.07.2012  2   b  5
4: 15.07.2012  1   a  5
```

I used adply function from plyr package to split duration in intervals by minute:

```
fn<-function(x){ 
  s<-seq(from = as.POSIXct(x$start), 
         to = as.POSIXct(x$end)-1,by = "mins")
# here s is a sequence of all minutes in the given interval
  df<-data.table(x$id,x$cat,s)

# return new data.table that contains each calendar minute for each id 
# and categoryy of the original data
  df
}
# run the function above for each row in the data.table
dd<-adply(dt,1,fn)

# extract the date from calendar minutes
dd[,day:=format(as.POSIXct(s,"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M%:%S"), "%d.%m.%Y")]

#calculate sum of all minutes of event for each day, id and category
dd[,.N,by=c("day","id","cat")][order(day,id,cat)]
```

The solution above perfectly suits my needs except the time it takes for calculation. When adply is run in a very big data and several categories defined in fn function, it feels like CPU runs forever.

I will highly appreciate any hint on how to use pure data.table functionality in this problem.

Comment: I totally agree with that, but I couldn't come up with better solution :(

Comment: Am I reading this wrong but aren't you simply taking the difference of two datetime columns?

Comment: For starters, your whole prcedure will run a lot faster if you will convert `start` and `end` to `POSIXct` class only once using ```dt[, `:=`(start = as.POSIXct(start), end = as.POSIXct(end))]``` instead of doing it per each row. Then `s` would be just `s <- seq(start, end, by = "min")`. I'm guessing this is your main bottle neck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest a few things

1. Convert to `as.POSIXct` only once instead of per each row.
2. instead of `adply` which creates a whole `data.table` in each iteration, just use `by` within the `data.table` scope.
3. In order to do so, simple create an row index using `.I`

Here's a quick attempt (I've used `substr` because it will be probably faster than `as.Date` or `as.POSIXct`. If you want it to be `Date` class again, use `res[, Date := as.IDate(Date)]` on the result istead of doing it by group).

```
dt[, `:=`(start = as.POSIXct(start), end = as.POSIXct(end), indx = .I)]
dt[, seq(start, end - 1L, by = "mins"), by = .(indx, id, cat)
   ][, .N, by = .(Date = substr(V1, 1L, 10L), id, cat)]
#          Date id cat  N
# 1: 2012-07-13  1   a 15
# 2: 2012-07-14  1   a  5
# 3: 2012-07-14  2   b  5
# 4: 2012-07-15  1   a  5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if this is faster.
It's still `data.table` in the background, but I'm using a `dplyr` syntax for the process.

```
library(data.table)

dt<-data.table(start=c("2012-07-13 23:45:00", "2012-07-14 15:30:00", 
                       "2012-07-14 23:57:00"), 
               end=c("2012-07-14 00:02:00", "2012-07-14 15:35:00", 
                     "2012-07-15 00:05:00"), id=c(1,2,1),cat=c("a","b","a"))

fn<-function(x){ 
  s<-seq(from = as.POSIXct(x$start), 
         to = as.POSIXct(x$end)-1,by = "mins")
  # here s is a sequence of all minutes in the given interval
  df<-data.table(x$id,x$cat,s)

  # return new data.table that contains each calendar minute for each id 
  # and categoryy of the original data
  df
}


library(dplyr)

dt %>%
  rowwise() %>%                        # for each row
  do(fn(.)) %>%                        # apply your function
  select(day=s, id=V1, cat=V2) %>%     # rename columns
  mutate(day = substr(day,1,10)) %>%   # keep only the day
  ungroup %>%
  group_by(day,id,cat) %>%         
  summarise(N=n()) %>%
  ungroup


# Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
# 
#           day    id   cat     N
#         (chr) (dbl) (chr) (int)
# 1 2012-07-13     1     a    15
# 2 2012-07-14     1     a     5
# 3 2012-07-14     2     b     5
# 4 2012-07-15     1     a     5
```